# Add a ! or a star to mark an outgoing email as urgent in Gmail

Tags: gmail

In Hotmail, you can click an exclamation mark "!" for an outgoing email to let the sender know it is important.

How do I do this in Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

A quick search seems to indicate that you can't set the priority of e-mails in Gmail, but that it does honour the settings applied by other mail clients.

See [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186535) for what it does with incoming e-mails.

Comment: Actually, the _important_ indicator in Gmail doesn't have anything to do with the priority set by the sender. See here how it works: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=186543

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing email may be you can try the Chrome extension [Mark as important in Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mark-as-important-in-gmai/choagfemmpcnmehbhkfoedlakeafcodp).

It will add an exclamation mark at the beginning of the subject. This extension does not modify the header of the email message.